# Laplace using $t$-shift

Tags: functions

Hello I'm doing a exercise that says to use the $t$-shift to find inverse laplace of
$$
F(s) = \frac{5s+4}{s^2} \cdot e^{-2s}.
$$

I'm not sure how to rewrite it so they have the same shift term on top and bottom

Comment: Since the inverse Laplace transform is linear, you probably want to express the rational term as a sum of two simpler terms.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(s)=\frac{5}{s}e^{-2s}+\frac{4}{s^2}e^{-2s}.$$
Now, if we apply the shift theorem we end up with

$$f(t)=5\,\mathcal U(t-2)+\dots.$$

You can do the other one, where $\mathcal U(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside step function:

$$\mathcal U(t-a)=\cases{1 & if $t\ge a$\\0 & if $t<a$}$$

Comment: I forgot you could split it up into fractions. I was just so used to finding a factor.

Comment: @Pyrons yes, sometimes it happens. Also if you haven't taken a look at convolution you should since it is very useful when dealing with Laplace Transform problems